Weird error when attempting to fit a GEE with an autoregressive correlation structure using `statsmodels`
I'm currently in the midst of trying to set up a simulation pipeline that evaluates GEE models on simulated data across several different correlation structures. I've gotten all the correlation structures to work correctly except for the AR-1 structure, which provides the following: ValueError('Autoregressive: unable to find right bracket'). I'm using the seizures dataset from geepack to perform the testing, and the below code is used to format the data and fit the model:
# libraries 
import rdatasets              # seizures dataset 
import numpy as np            # linear algebra tools 
import pandas as pd           # DataFrame manipulation
import statsmodels.api as sm  # GEE implementation
# data 
seizure = rdatasets.data('geepack', item='seizure')
seizure['id'] = range(1, len(seizure) + 1)
seizure = seizure.melt(id_vars=['id', 'age', 'trt'], 
                       value_vars=['base'] + [col for col in seizure.columns if col.startswith('y')],
                       var_name='period', 
                       value_name='seizures')
seizure['exposure'] = np.where(seizure['period'] == 'base', 8, 2)
seizure['log_exposure'] = np.log(seizure['exposure'])
seizure = seizure.sort_values(by=['id', 'period'], ascending=True)
seizure['time'] = seizure.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1
# modeling 
gee = sm.GEE.from_formula('seizures ~ age + trt', 
                          groups='id', 
                          time='time', 
                          data=seizure, 
                          cov_struct=sm.cov_struct.Autoregressive(), 
                          family=sm.families.Poisson(link=sm.families.links.Log()), 
                          offset='log_exposure')
geemod = gee.fit()

The above code works just fine with the exchangeable and unstructured correlation structures, but for some reason the autoregressive structure fails. I'll note that when fitting an equivalent model in R using geepack the AR-1 structure works just fine, so I don't think the data itself is a problem. Any help is greatly appreciated !

what is the ar coefficient when estimating with geepack?

geepack does not estimate the same AR-1 model -- sm.GEE is a continuous-time AR-1 and geepack is a discrete-time AR-1, which is much easier to estimate

@ThomasLumley that makes sense - so is it safe to assume that the data itself is the issue, not the way i've formatted the function call ?

I don't know that it's safe to assume that, but it's certainly possible.

IIRC, then cov_struct "Stationary" in statsmodels allows for discrete time AR. unit test examples starting at https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/genmod/tests/test_gee.py#L1334

The exception in statsmodels is raised, when the Autoregressive parameter is b_rgt > 1. - 1e-6. It assumes process is stationary and bounded away from 1. So a (near) non-stationary estimated process is not allowed, and raises exception instead of forcing stationarity.
